# Eclipse XLRD Import Error

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, importerror

I've installed xlrd 0.9.2 on python7.3 (xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7) using "python setup.py install" on windows-7 32-bit. Everything looks good and xlrd folder was created at C:\python27\Lib\site-packages.

But on Eclipse when trying to import xlrd I get an error `"unresolved import: xlrd"`.
I've tried to solve by explicitly adding xlrd to pydev lib (at window/Preferences/PyDev/Interpreter - Python/libraries) but it did not help.
I've of-course searched for help on the WEB, still no luck.

Will appreciate any advice.

Comment: Note: when running python27 from command line, import xlrd works fine, so there must be something wrong I'm doing with Eclipse

Comment: Solved with right click on xlrd => quick fix => @unresolvedimport